# Send verification code via email but not activating on Yii

Tags: php, yii

my question is account activation from email code. currently function send email code but logged in without activation (Create new user without click verification link).

This my controller code-

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model=new User;

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        $image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        if($image!=NULL)
        {
            $model->image = $image; 

            $image->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/'.$image);                       
        }

        $model->registration_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $model->user_status= 'Disabled';

        $activation_code= mt_rand(0x000000, 0xffffff); 

        $model->activation_code=$activation_code;

        if($model->save())
        {
            $to =$_POST['User']['email']; 

            $User=User::model()->find(
                '"email"=:email', array(':email'=>$to)
            );  

            $subject = "Activate your account on www.polymyositisresearch.org";


            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?='; 

            echo $comment = 
            "<html>
                <body> 
                    \r\nPlease<a href=".Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("user/signup-confirmation", 
                    array("secure_activation_key"=>$activation_code))." > Click here </a> to activate your account.
                    \r\nThank you.
                </body>
            </html>";


            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: www.polymyositisresearch.org< admin@polymyositisresearch.org>' . "\r\n";

            if(mail($to,$subject,$comment,$headers))
            {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','An activation email has sent to your email address. 
                Please activate your account and continue to next step on polymyositisresearch.org. Thank you.');
                $this->refresh();
            }
            else
                echo "SMTP Server Error";
        }
        else    
        {
            $model->password = ''; // if the validate failed, clear out the password before re-rendering the form
            $model->verifyPassword = '';
        }
    }

    $this->render('sign-up',array('user'=>$model));
}
```

Activation function-

```
public function actionSignupconfirmation($secure_activation_key)
{   
    $User=User::model()->find(
        'activation_code=:activation_code', array(':activation_code'=>$secure_activation_key)
    );  

    if($User!=NULL)
    {           
        if($User->activation_code==$secure_activation_key)
        {
            $activate_code= mt_rand(0x000000, 0xffffff); 

            $User->activation_code=$activate_code;
            $User->user_status= 'Enabled';

            $User->save(false);

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Congrats! Your account has been verified successfully. Please login to access your account. Thank you.');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Account confirmation unsuccessful. Please try again.');
        //$this->refresh();
    }

    $this->render('signup-confirmation');
}
```

A little help is much appreciated. I need some guidance to after click verification email then create new users.

Comment: please specify what exactly is the help you expect and what is your current problem + how did you try do achieve the goal

Comment: Hi **mikus** My problem is this function send verification code via email but this verification is not required for new users, automatically create new users without verify email. i need after click verification email then create new users. What can I do now?

Comment: if I understood correctly all you need to do is to check User.user_status during login, if it is 'Disabled' reject login. No idea how your login logic looks like, though, but the topic should be pretty much covered in tutorials.

Comment: Hi **mikus** Updated my status please check

Comment: You have to create the user model before it's validated so if I understand correctly what you want isn't possible, you only want to create the user model when they click the link? That's can't work. Also if you're just starting this project I'd recommend using Yii2 instead. Yii 1 isn't recommended for new projects anymore.

Comment: But if they can log in without been verified all you have to do is in your Login model, check that user_status = 'disabled'